# Backing up the open-source edition of Zimbra mail

Tags: email, imap, incremental-backup, zimbra

Background:

We run the [open-source edition of Zimbra mail](http://www.zimbra.com/downloads/os-downloads.html) (5, not 6 yet) and while it's not something that we want to encourage (prevention is better than a cure), we currently have no way of backing up (or restoring) mail in the system. The Network (paid) Edition has automated 
backups; [various user-contributed solutions](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Open_Source_Edition_Backup_Procedure) exist for the open source edition.

My question in two parts:

1. Does anyone have experience performing backups on Zimbra OSE? I'm particularly interested in snapshot backups over ssh/rsync (we use [`dirvish`](http://www.dirvish.org) for filesystem backups), and we don't use LVM (`/opt/zimbra/store/` is it's own partition, the server is Ubuntu on ESXi).
2. If backup/restore on a live system is "too hard", I'm happy to settle for backing up only specific shared accounts that are never logged into directly (and hence I have the password for) over IMAP. I'd be interested in recommendations for a command-line email client that

   1. can be automated to retrieve messages & folders (e.g. given command line parameters / config file, will log in to account, fetch new email, quit)
   2. stores email in the [maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/maildir) format, which is nicer to backup than [mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/mbox)

I'm leaning towards the second with something like [isync](http://isync.sf.net), since the mail system has over 100GB of messages at present.

Answer (score 1):

As no one posted until now, I will mention zmbak script from:
http://www.osoffice.de/downloads/viewcategory-7.html.
I'm currently testing it.
After reading it, I can say it's wort a try.
I guess you can adapt this to your needs.

HTH

Comment: Agreed - better actually back up your Zimbra file system than the IMAP mailboxes - you'd lose lots of the Zimbra setup information and it would be hard to restore it; as well as calendar etc

Answer (score 0):

Another option is LVM snapshots.  Not ideal, but they'll keep the filesystem state stable long enough to image the parts you care about, even on a live system.

Of course it would be best to bring the server down to do backups.

As far as automatically retrieving email, it sounds like you want fetchmail:

http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/97/using-fetchmail-and-procmail-for-maildir-style-storage-from-a-pop3-account/

Answer (score 0):

As the Zimbra install is in vSphere (and backed by a SAN), the simplest backup method has ended up being a combination of

- SAN snapshots
- VM backups

Account data can then be restored by restoring a backup or snapshot, exporting from the restored VM and re-importing into the live system.

We're going to investigate [ZeXtras](http://www.zextras.com/) which includes real-time backup in the future; this does cost money but is significantly cheaper than the licensing for Zimbra Network Edition, even at education / charity rates.